# getElementById to getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code which is working. But it is only for one textarea because it uses ID. However i would like to use this for all textareas that on my code. I have tried getElementsByClassName but it didn't work.

HTML:

`<textarea id="textarea1" class="form-control page-textarea" rows="4" style="height:92px;" name="memory" placeholder="new comment..."></textarea>`

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var textarea = document.getElementById("textarea1");
  var limit = 200;

textarea.oninput = function() {
  textarea.style.height = "";
  textarea.style.height = Math.min(textarea.scrollHeight, limit) + "px";

  if(textarea.style.height == "92px"){
    textarea.style.overflow = "hidden";
  } else if(textarea.style.height < limit  + "px"){
    textarea.style.overflow = "hidden";
  } else {
    textarea.style.overflow = "auto";
  }
};
</script>
```

How do i do this?

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names. You will have to loop through all the child elements.

Comment: You say that the code which doesn't work uses `getElementsByClassName`, but the code you have shown us doesn't. Show us the code that does not work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) you'll see that `getElementsByClassName` returns a `HTMLCollection`. You will have to loop through all the child elements to make it work.

```
var textareas = document.getElementsByClassName("form-control page-textarea");
var limit = 200;

for(var i=0, length= textareas.length; i < length; i++){
   var textarea = textareas[i];
   textarea.oninput = function() {
    this.style.height = "";
    this.style.height = Math.min(this.scrollHeight, limit) + "px";

    if(this.style.height == "92px"){
      this.style.overflow = "hidden";
    } else if(this.style.height < limit  + "px"){
      this.style.overflow = "hidden";
    } else {
      this.style.overflow = "auto";
    }
  };
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tDDMT/)

Comment: unfortunately, it didn't work

Comment: please define 'it didn't work'

Comment: that's too bad then...

Comment: my code works for only one, your code does not even work for one.

Comment: Works for me though, check the fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

I thing event delegation is much better approach in this situation. 
Check this code.

```
document.addEventListener('input', function(event) {
    var limit = 200;
    if(event.target.getAttribute("class") == "form-control page-textarea") {
      var target = event.target;
      target.style.height = "";
     target.style.height = Math.min(target.scrollHeight, limit) + "px";

     if(target.style.height == "92px"){
       target.style.overflow = "hidden";
     } else if(target.style.height < limit  + "px"){
       target.style.overflow = "hidden";
     } else {
       target.style.overflow = "auto";
     }   
    }
}, false);
```

Here is working jsFiddle. 
http://jsfiddle.net/yg6sS/5/
In this way we save loop trought elements.

Answer (score -2):

```
 use jquery to easily solve this 
    $(function() {
            $("textarea").css("border", "3px solid red");

                              (OR)
            $("textarea").css('border':'3px solid red','color':'Green');
    });
```